# Can i use a button within a NSview to change views using NSViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a view controller and 5 views. Currently I use a pop-up in mainMenu.xib to access the NSObject AppController which uses the view controller to change between views.

I know that using storyboards in IOS you can use a button within a view to change between views.  Is this possible in OSX?

Can I put a button in FirstViewController.xib to access the changeViewController in my AppController object?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OSX your views will appear in a NSWindow.  So what you need to do is, upon pressing that button (which fires a IBAction), tell your window (or subclassed NSWindow or NSWindowController) that you want to switch views.

(which you can do via removeSubview or addSubview to the [NSWindow's contentView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/contentView))

You don't have segues or storyboards in MacOS applications, b.t.w.

Answer (score 0):

At the 2014 WWDC they introduced
[Storyboards for MacOS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#212).  So IOS Developers can feel more at home creating UI for the Mac.